# Unit Testing navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }) using Jest (React)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I Tried to mock this function

```
const location = window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation;
if (location) {
  location.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      handleChangeLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
  );
}
navigator.permissions
  .query({ name: 'geolocation' })
  .then((permission) => {
    permission.onchange = function () {
      if (permission.state === 'granted') {
        location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          handleChangeLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        });
      } else if (permission.state === 'denied') {
        // Todo
      }
    };
  });
```

so far what i've tried is
Create Global Navigator at setupTest.js

```
const mockGeolocation = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce((success) => Promise.resolve(success({
      coords: {
        latitude: 51.1,
        longitude: 45.3,
      },
    }))),
};
global.navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation;
```

but ended up at error

[image]

I tried to solve this by adding`jest.spyOn(window.navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }), 'onchange', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce('granted');`
but i think there's some mistake cause it's says undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that `navigator.permissions` is undefined. Jest uses JSDOM to mimic real DOM in Node.js environment and doesn't have a lot of APIs that a browser would.

All missing globals need to be stubbed manually:

```
navigator.permissions = { query: jest.fn() };
navigator.geolocation = { getCurrentPosition: jest.fn() };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock `navigator.permissions.query`. Try the following:

```
global.navigator.permissions = {
  query: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ state: 'granted' })),
};
```

Above state's value could be `granted`, `denied` or `prompt`.

Overall mock `navigator.geolocation` and `navigator.permissions` like the follwoing:

```
  global.navigator.geolocation = {
    getCurrentPosition: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((success) =>
      Promise.resolve(
        success({
          coords: {
            latitude: 43.21,
            longitude: -87.654321,
          },
        })
      )
    ),
  };
```

```
  global.navigator.permissions = {
    query: jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ state: 'granted' })),
  };
```

Comment: there is a shorthand version `jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ state: 'granted' })`